# GCM: Subscribe Chrome extension to a topic

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to develop a Chrome extension which can receive notifications using GCM. When the extension is first installed, I register it using `chrome.gcm.register(['my_sender_id'], function(registration_id) { console.log(registration_id); });`.

I would like to send push messages to everyone who has the extension installed. However, the problem is that GCM requires you to specify the registration ID's of everyone you want to send the message to; you can't just send it to everyone who's connected to the sender ID.

While it would be possible to push the registration ID to a database when the extension is installed, and then consult this database each time I want to send a message, this solution seems sub-optimal (also from a security point of view, since the pushing of the registration ID would be done client-side).

However, Google introduced a solution for this a few years ago: [topics](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging). It's possible to simply register each device to a 'global' topic (for example) and when you then want to send a message, you only have to specify the 'global' topic as the receiver. However, I can't find how this registration process is done for Chrome extensions. I've looked everywhere, but it seems like Chrome's GCM module doesn't support this yet. Am I correct in this and if so, is there an alternative way to pull this off?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you call [chrome.instanceID.getToken](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/instanceID#method-getToken) and then use the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) from your server to subscribe to a topic, it seems to work, but then the chrome extension doesn't get messages when you push to that topic, so I'm not sure if Google just needs to enable something on their side to make it work. But this is the closest I could get to it in any case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `chrome.instanceID` API. I was having some issues with `chrome.gcm` and didn't knew there is an api separately.

Comment: Topic messaging doesn't work with chrome extensions. Strange!!

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Thanks for the great feedback. There is no way at the moment to subscribe to a topic from a browser. We're aware that having such an API would simplify the development model. We'd love to add this to Firebase, but as usual can't make any promises or commitments.

Comment: Cool! It's a shame this is not available yet, but I'm happy to hear you're listening to user feedback. I'll just keep my fingers crossed for now :-)